# Deleting rows based on groupby conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe with ("ID", "Month" and "status"). Status is regarding "Churn"= 1 and 'Not Churn" = 2.

```
     ID     Month   Status
     3863   201707  1
     3863   201708  1
     3863   201709  1
     3863   201710  1
     3863   201711  1
     3863   201712  1
     3863   201801  1
     3863   201802  1
     3863   201803  1
     3863   201804  1
     3863   201805  1
     3863   201806  1
     3863   201807  2
     3863   201808  2
     3863   201809  2
     3863   201810  2
     3863   201811  2
     3863   201812  2
     3863   201901  2
     3863   201902  2
     3863   201903  2
     3863   201904  2
     3863   201905  2
     3863   201906  2
     3863   201907  2
     3863   201908  1
     3863   201909  1
     3863   201910  1
     3863   201911  1
     3863   201912  1
```

I have to delete all rows with Status = 1 (churn) for the customer who in the observed period has Status= 2 but after Status=1 (the customer was inactive and then reactivate itself)

After transformation dataframe should look like

```
     ID     Month   Status
     3863   201807  2
     3863   201808  2
     3863   201809  2
     3863   201810  2
     3863   201811  2
     3863   201812  2
     3863   201901  2
     3863   201902  2
     3863   201903  2
     3863   201904  2
     3863   201905  2
     3863   201906  2
     3863   201907  2
     3863   201908  1
```

Comment: what is being grouped? this looks like a fairly straight forward `loc` example :)

Comment: grouping by ID and status? If you have some idea send me that I can try

Comment: With your current information, both cases are simply a filter on the status `df[df.Status != 1]`

Comment: I see now that I didn't explain correctly. I added the case when a customer has status =2 and then changes to status=1. That row must stay because that is information about churn

Comment: I see the problem like this:
 delete all rows with status=1 for the customer if there is no row with status =2
delete all rows with status=1 for the customer if there is a row with status =2 but a month for status =2 is greater than for status=1

Comment: Is you expected output for case 1 or 2?

Comment: It would be perfect for both :). Actually that is part of cleaning and preparing data set for Churn prediction uce case. Rows which I want to delete have no influence on the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the following function:

```
def fn(grp):
    if ~grp.Status.eq(2).any():
        # No rows with Status == 2 -> return nothing
        return None
    srt = grp.sort_values('Month')  # Sort rows
    # Status == 1 after Status == 2
    stat2after1 = srt.Status.shift().eq(1) & srt.Status.eq(2)
    if stat2after1.any():           # Something found
        cs = srt.Status.eq(2).cumsum()
        # Return rows from the first with Status == 2 on
        return srt[cs.gt(0)]
    return srt      # Return all rows (sorted)
```

Then, to get the result, apply it to each group:

```
df.groupby('ID').apply(fn).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

Comment: It works, tnx, only one thing, when the # Status == 2 after Status == 1 -> drop rows with Status == 1 only for the rows which are before status 2, not all (rows with status 1 after rows with status 2). Is it possible to correct function for that?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for **case 1** and [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) with [`GroupBy.bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.bfill.html) for **case 2**:

```
case1 = df['Status'].eq(1).groupby(df['ID']).transform('all')
case2 = (df['Status'].where(df['Status'].ne(1))
                     .groupby(df['ID'])
                     .bfill()
                     .eq(2)
                     .mul(df['Status'].eq(1)))
df_filtered = df.loc[~(case1|case2)]
print(df_filtered)

      ID   Month  Status
7   2311  201710       2
8   2311  201711       2
9   2311  201712       2
10  2312  201708       2
11  2312  201709       2
12  2312  201710       2
13  2312  201711       2
14  2312  201712       1
```

Comment: probably i am not using a correct example here but in real dataset this transformation doesn't work

Comment: I will try to better explain just case 2 for the beginning

Comment: you should have asked another new question in stackoverflow, since we have taken time to solve the previous one and now you have changed it

Comment: you are right but it is also important to solve the problem. I had idea to better explain the problem

Comment: You explained a problem that had nothing to do with it. if you change the problem now people will see the question and think that this answer is wrong and will vote against it, when it is not. It is correct for the initial question. You can ask another new question and pose the problem correctly

Comment: sorry my mistake, i just started with stack.